# Office 365 Mail Rest API retrieving attached *.eml file

Tags: curl, outlook, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

I have some email archive with different email address what should keep emails with attachments like: ***.pdf, *.png, *.eml** and other.

> I am using embedded in MS Outlook Add-on to get authKeys, then
>   send them on PHP backend, where creating CURL requests to retrieve
>   data.

There is almost no problems with retrieving array of attachments with using request:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{messageid}/attachments/
```

But "special type": **Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment** have no content, only reference to other item.

I can get **parsed** by Microsoft API content for **Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment** item by using request:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{messageid}/attachments/{AttachmentId}?$expand=Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment/Item
```

But with file content again i need to do extra work to parce it back and send extra requests to get attachments what was inside of this ***.eml** file...
 *what if i have multiply layers of attachments?*

There is any way i can get actual ***.eml** file, like other attachments(with **ContentBytes** property)?

*I Know we have here couple of similar questions but i still can't find answer even in official documentation, if i am missing something please let me know! Thanks!*

Comment: Did you find any answer to your question ?

Comment: Nope, when you use .eml file as an attachments MS server record it as an actual email, and you can retrieve data by Email-ID similar to original email, it creates extra layer of complexity but at least it's something you can work with. May be in 2 years something changed... i wasn't able to revisit code of this app for a long time...